# laravel events - call another event from an event

Tags: events, laravel

My `EventServiceProvider` has the following,

```
'App\Events\EventCreated' => [
            'App\Handlers\Events\EventCreatedNotifications',
            'App\Handlers\Events\EventCreatedMail'
        ],
```

I want to call the `EventCreatedMail` event from the `EventCreatedNotifications` by passing parameters, is it possible to do this.

Comment: Well when you call `EventCreatedNotifications` event, by triggering the `App\Events\EventCreated`, both events `EventCreatedNotifications` and  `EventCreatedMail` will be triigered I do not see the point to manually triggering the second event, as it will be triggered anyways?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Shaddy. I know both the events will be triggered when eventcreated is triggered. Is it possible to trigger the EventCreatedMail like event(new \App\Events\EventCreatedMail($event->id, $input['notify'])); from EventCreateNotifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When triggering `App\Events\EventCreated` event, all event classes registered for this event will be triggered. What you are asking is not good in terms of code organization. Your `EventCreatedMail` will be called annyways when `EventCreatedNotifications` is called. Yes, you can instantiate new `EventCreatedMail` class and call it's handle function to simulate calling the event, but this is wrong and you should not do it.

Instead you can just separate both events, and then you can easily call `EventCreatedMail` from where you want, like this:

```
'App\Events\EventCreated' => [
    'App\Handlers\Events\EventCreatedNotifications',
],
'App\Events\CreatedNotification' => [
    'App\Handlers\Events\EventCreatedMail'
],
```

After that you can call

```
event(new \App\Events\CreatedNotification($event->id, $input['notify']));
```

From your first event.